# R shiny - weird resizing lag when loading plots from slow computations upon first opening app

Tags: r, shiny

My code is at the end of this post, but I'll state the problem first. I have a page that should show plots (generated from synthetic data) upon page load. Two of the plots take some time, and for this reason when the page loads, the formatting usually looks quite funky as you can see below. Sometimes it fixes itself, and sometimes it doesn't fix itself at all before the user presses a button to regenerate a plot. You can see the lagged version here:

[image: kag]

And here you can see the version when it's finished/recovered:

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

I am pasting my code below:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme="style.css",

    headerPanel("Atomic point contact break-junction traces"),

    #row 1
    fluidRow(
      column(1),

      column(3, wellPanel(
        br(),
        p("Click the button to see a new trace.", align="center"),
        br(),
        actionButton('samp','New Sample', align="center")
      )),

      column(1),

      column(3, wellPanel(
        plotOutput("trace", height="300px", width = "300px")
      )),

      column(3, wellPanel(
        plotOutput("G0steps", height="300px", width = "300px")
      ))
    ),


    #row 2
    fluidRow(

      column(1),

      column(3, wellPanel(
        br(),
        p("Click the button to see an aligned 2d histogram"),
        actionButton('button2D', 'See Steps')

      )),

      column(2),

      column(4, wellPanel(
        plotOutput("hist2D")
      ))
    ),

    #row 3
    fluidRow(

      column(1),

      column(3, wellPanel(
        br(),
        p("Click the button to see steps identified"),
        actionButton('buttonSteps', 'See Steps'),
        br(),
        p("Click the button to see clusters of steps identified"),
        actionButton('clusterButton', 'See Clusters')
      )),

      column(1),

      column(3, wellPanel(
        plotOutput("stepsShow")
      )),

      column(1),  

      column(3, wellPanel(
        plotOutput("clustersShow")
      ))
    )

    ))
```

And here is server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # initial loading of plots:
  trace = makeTrace()
  output$trace <- renderPlot({
    plot(trace)
  })
  output$G0steps <- renderPlot({
    plot(alignG(.1, trace ))
  })
  output$stepsShow <- renderPlot({
    findJumps(beginG =1.5, endG = .1, trace = makeTrace(), loq=1)
  })

  output$hist2D <- renderPlot({
    make2DHist()
  })

  output$clustersShow <- renderPlot({
    clust.size <- 3
    numTraces <-30
    list_df <- makeClusters(numTraces)
    df1     <- list_df[[1]]
    drops     <- c("Trace")
    df1.clust <- df1[,!(names(df1) %in% drops)]
    df1C            <- bestCluster(df1.clust, clust.size, df1)
    df1C$clusterCat <- factor(df1C$Cluster)
    plot.cats       <- ggplot(df1C, aes(x=Noise, y = AvgC), colour=clusterCat) + geom_point( aes(color=clusterCat, size=4)) 
        plot.cats
  })



  #row 1
      observe({
        if(input$samp > 0) {
          trace = makeTrace()
          output$trace <- renderPlot({
            plot(trace)
          })
          output$G0steps <- renderPlot({
            plot(alignG(.1, trace ))
          })
        }
      })


  #row 2
  observe({
    if(input$button2D > 0) {
      make2DHist()
      output$hist2D <- renderPlot({
        make2DHist()
      })
    }
  })

  #row 3
  observe({
    if(input$buttonSteps > 0) {
      findJumps(beginG =1.5, endG = .1, trace = makeTrace(), loq=1)
      output$stepsShow <- renderPlot({
        findJumps(beginG =1.5, endG = .1, trace = makeTrace(), loq=1)
      })
    }
  })

  observe({
    if(input$clusterButton > 0) {
      clust.size <- 3
      numTraces <-30
      list_df <- makeClusters(numTraces)
      df1     <- list_df[[1]]
      drops     <- c("Trace")
      df1.clust <- df1[,!(names(df1) %in% drops)]
      df1C            <- bestCluster(df1.clust, clust.size, df1)
      df1C$clusterCat <- factor(df1C$Cluster)
      plot.cats       <- ggplot(df1C, aes(x=Noise, y = AvgC), colour=clusterCat) + geom_point( aes(color=clusterCat, size=4)) 
      plot.cats

      output$clustersShow <- renderPlot({
        plot.cats
      })
    }
  })


})
```

Answer (score 0):

This weird resizing lag can be avoided by setting the height and width in plotOutput. Apparently leaving it at auto does not work if you want it loaded correctly from the start.